# EXT js save CellEditing in BBDD sql

Tags: javascript, extjs

i have a little question, i have a web application, and i need that when i show in a grid a list of register i can modified one fields, and that fields modificied will be saved in the bbdd.

My code is the next

```
 var gridTablaConsulta = Ext.create('Ext.grid.GridPanel', {
    title:'Consulta Tabla lotes',
    store: storeTabla,
    columns: [
        Ext.create('Ext.grid.RowNumberer'),
        {text: "NRBE", width: 60, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'NRBE'},
        {text: "APLIC", width: 60, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'APLIC'},
        {text: "FORM", width: 60, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'FORM'},
        {text: "VERFOR", width: 60, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'VERFOR'},
        {text: "FECLOT", width: 60, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'FECLOT'},
        {text: "HORLOT", width: 60, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'HORLOT'},
        {text: "TIPPAPLO", width: 60, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'TIPPAPLO'},
        {text: "TAMPAP", width: 60, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'TAMPAP'},
        {text: "FECINIIM", width: 60, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'FECINIIM'},
        {text: "FECINIOB", width: 60, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'FECINIOB'},
        {text: "ESTLOT", width: 60, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'ESTLOT'},
        {text: "TOTPAGGE", width: 60, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'TOTPAGGE'},
        {text: "TOTPAGIM", width: 60, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'TOTPAGIM'},
        {text: "DESLOT", width: 60, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'DESLOT'},
        {text: "TIPDIF", width: 60, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'TIPDIF', editor: {xtype:'textfield', allowBlank:false}},
        {text: "DIADIF", width: 60, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'DIADIF', editor: {xtype:'textfield', allowBlank:false} },
        {text: "FECALT", width: 60, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'FECALT'},
        {text: "FECMOD", width: 60, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'FECMOD'},
        {text: "TERMOD", width: 60, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'TERMOD'},
        {text: "HORMOD", width: 60, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'HORMOD'}
    ],
    selType: 'rowmodel',
    plugins: [
        Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing', {
            clicksToEdit: 2
        })
    ],

    listeners: {
        edit: function(e){
            Ext.Ajax.request({
                url: 'http://localhost:8080/MyMaver/ServletTablaLotes',
                method: 'POST',

                params: {
                    Funcionalidad: 'Modificar',
                    DPNrbe: Ext.getCmp('DPNrbe').getValue(),
                    DPAplic: Ext.getCmp('DPAplic').getValue(),
                    DPForm:Ext.getCmp('DPForm').getValue(), 
                    DPVersFor: Ext.getCmp('DPVerFor').getValue(),
                    DPFecLot: Ext.getCmp('DPFecLot').getValue(),
                    DPHorLot: Ext.getCmp('DPHorLot').getValue(),
                    DPTippApl: Ext.getCmp('DPTippApl').getValue(),
                    DPTamPap: Ext.getCmp('DPTamPap').getValue(),
                    DPFecinIm: Ext.getCmp('DPFecinIm').getValue(),
                    DPFeciNio: Ext.getCmp('DPFeciNio').getValue(),
                    DPEstLot: Ext.getCmp('DPEstLot').getValue(),
                    DPTotPagge: Ext.getCmp('DPTotPagge').getValue(),
                    DPTotPagim: Ext.getCmp('DPTotPagim').getValue(),
                    DPDesLot: Ext.getCmp('DPDesLot').getValue(),
                    DPTipDif: Ext.getCmp('DPTipDif').getValue(),
                    DPDiaDif: Ext.getCmp('DPDiaDif').getValue(),
                    Entorno:  Ext.getCmp('Entorno').getValue()
                 },
                success: function(){

                      var text = response.responseText;
                        // process server response here
                      respuestaModificacion(text);

                    },
                    failure:  function (){
                    alert("Desde failure");
                    },
                    exception: function (){
                   alert("Desde exception");
                 }
            });
        }
    }


});
```

Thanks for all.

I pasted the code in my servlet:

```
 private void tratarPeticionesEntrantes(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    if(request.getParameter("Funcionalidad")==null || request.getParameter("Funcionaldiad")==""){
        RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("/jsp/PantallasGestion/tablaLotes.jsp");

        rd.forward(request,response);
    }else{
        System.out.println("prueba entrada");
        JSONObject json=tratarPeticion(request);
        System.out.println(json.toJSONString());
        PrintWriter escritorRespuesta=response.getWriter();
        escritorRespuesta.println(json.toJSONString());
        //escritorRespuesta.println();
        escritorRespuesta.flush();
        escritorRespuesta.close();
    }
}




//JSON

private JSONObject tratarPeticion(HttpServletRequest request){
    JSONObject respuesta=null;
    String parametroFuncionalidad=request.getParameter("Funcionalidad");
    System.out.println(request.getParameter("Funcionalidad"));

    if(parametroFuncionalidad!=null && parametroFuncionalidad!=""){
        if(parametroFuncionalidad.equalsIgnoreCase("CONSULTA")){
            respuesta=tratarPeticionConsulta(request);

        }else if(parametroFuncionalidad.equalsIgnoreCase("MODIFICAR")){
            respuesta=tratarPeticionModificacion(request);      
        }else if(parametroFuncionalidad.equalsIgnoreCase("INSERTAR")){
            respuesta=tratarPeticionAlta(request);
            System.out.println("aqui entra");
        }else if(parametroFuncionalidad.equalsIgnoreCase("ELIMINAR")){
            respuesta=tratarPeticionBaja(request);  
        }

    }
    return respuesta;       
}



private JSONArray tipoPapelesToArray(ArrayList<TablaLotes> papeles){
    JSONArray list = new JSONArray();
    for(int i=0;i<papeles.size();i++){
        JSONObject elemento1=new JSONObject();
        elemento1.put("NRBE",papeles.get(i).getEntidad());
        elemento1.put("APLIC",papeles.get(i).getAplicacion());
        elemento1.put("FORM",papeles.get(i).getFormulario());
        elemento1.put("VERFOR",papeles.get(i).getVersion());
        elemento1.put("FECLOT",papeles.get(i).getFecha_lote());
        elemento1.put("HORLOT",papeles.get(i).getHora_lote());
        elemento1.put("TIPPAPLO",papeles.get(i).getTipoPapel());
        elemento1.put("TAMPAP",papeles.get(i).getTamanoPapel());
        elemento1.put("FECINIIM",papeles.get(i).getFecha_inicio());
        elemento1.put("FECINIOB",papeles.get(i).getFecha_obligada());
        elemento1.put("ESTLOT",papeles.get(i).getEstado());
        elemento1.put("TOTPAGGE",papeles.get(i).getTotalPaginasGen());
        elemento1.put("TOTPAGIM",papeles.get(i).getTotalPaginasImpr());
        elemento1.put("DESLOT",papeles.get(i).getDescLote());
        elemento1.put("TIPDIF",papeles.get(i).getTipoDiferimiento());
        elemento1.put("DIADIF",papeles.get(i).getDiasDiferi());
        elemento1.put("FECALT",papeles.get(i).getFechaAlta());
        elemento1.put("FECMOD",papeles.get(i).getFechaModificacion());
        elemento1.put("TERMOD",papeles.get(i).getUsuarioModificacion());
        elemento1.put("HORMOD",papeles.get(i).getHoraModificacion());
        list.add(elemento1);
    }
    return list;
}


 private String[] obtenerCamposParaModificacion(HttpServletRequest request){
    ArrayList<String> elementosAux=new ArrayList<String>();
    if(request.getParameter("DPNrbe")!=null && request.getParameter("DPNrbe").trim()!="")
    {
        elementosAux.add("NRBE~"+request.getParameter("DPNrbe"));

    }

    if(request.getParameter("DPAplic")!=null && request.getParameter("DPAplic").trim()!="")
    {
        elementosAux.add("APLIC~"+request.getParameter("DPAplic"));

    }

    if(request.getParameter("DPForm")!=null && request.getParameter("DPForm").trim()!="")
    {
        elementosAux.add("FORM~"+request.getParameter("DPForm"));

    }


    if(request.getParameter("DPVerFor")!=null && request.getParameter("DPVerFor").trim()!="")
    {
        elementosAux.add("VERFOR~"+request.getParameter("DPVerFor"));

    }



    if(request.getParameter("DPFecLot")!=null && request.getParameter("DPFecLot").trim()!="")
    {
        elementosAux.add("FECLOT~"+request.getParameter("DPFecLot"));

    }



    if(request.getParameter("DPHorLot")!=null && request.getParameter("DPHorLot").trim()!="")
    {
        elementosAux.add("HORLOT~"+request.getParameter("DPHorLot"));

    }


    if(request.getParameter("DPTippApl")!=null && request.getParameter("DPTippApl").trim()!="")
    {
        elementosAux.add("TIPPAPLO~"+request.getParameter("DPTippApl"));

    }


    if(request.getParameter("DPTamPap")!=null && request.getParameter("DPTamPap").trim()!="")
    {
        elementosAux.add("TAMPAP~"+request.getParameter("DPTamPap"));

    }



    if(request.getParameter("DPFecinIm")!=null && request.getParameter("DPFecinIm").trim()!="")
    {
        elementosAux.add("FECINIIM~"+request.getParameter("DPFecinIm"));

    }


    if(request.getParameter("DPFeciNio")!=null && request.getParameter("DPFeciNio").trim()!="")
    {
        elementosAux.add("FECINIOB~"+request.getParameter("DPFeciNio"));

    }



    if(request.getParameter("DPEstLot")!=null && request.getParameter("DPEstLot").trim()!="")
    {
        elementosAux.add("ESTLOT~"+request.getParameter("DPEstLot"));

    }



    if(request.getParameter("DPTotPagge")!=null && request.getParameter("DPTotPagge").trim()!="")
    {
        elementosAux.add("TOTPAGGE~"+request.getParameter("DPTotPagge"));

    }


    if(request.getParameter("DPTotPagim")!=null && request.getParameter("DPTotPagim").trim()!="")
    {   
        elementosAux.add("TOTPAGIM~"+request.getParameter("DPTotPagim"));

    }


    if(request.getParameter("DPDesLot")!=null && request.getParameter("DPDesLot").trim()!="")
    {   
        elementosAux.add("DESLOT~"+request.getParameter("DPDesLot"));
    }

    if(request.getParameter("DPDesLot")!=null && request.getParameter("DPDesLot").trim()!="")
    {   
        elementosAux.add("DESLOT~"+request.getParameter("DPDesLot"));
    }

    if(request.getParameter("DPTipDif")!=null && request.getParameter("DPTipDif").trim()!="")
    {   
        elementosAux.add("TIPDIF~"+request.getParameter("DPTipDif"));
    }

    if(request.getParameter("DPDiaDif")!=null && request.getParameter("DPDiaDif").trim()!="")
    {   
        elementosAux.add("DIADIF~"+request.getParameter("DPDiaDif"));
    }

    String [] elementos=new String[elementosAux.size()];
    return elementosAux.toArray(elementos);
}


private JSONObject tratarPeticionModificacion(HttpServletRequest request){
    TablaLotesDAO papelDAO=new TablaLotesDAO();
    String [] camposAObtener={"TODOS"};
    String entorno="DESARROLLO";
    if(request.getParameter("Entorno")!=null && request.getParameter("Entorno").trim()!="")
        entorno=request.getParameter("Entorno");
    ArrayList<TablaLotes> papeles=papelDAO.obtenerParaModificar(obtenerCamposParaModificacion(request),entorno);

    JSONObject respuesta = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray list = tipoPapelesToArray(papeles);       
    respuesta.put("TiposPapel",list);
    return respuesta;
}
```

Now i am trying this:

```
    listeners: {
         edit: function(e, context){


             var record = context.record;

             var recordData = record.getData();

             recordData.Funcionalidad = 'Modificar';

             Ext.Ajax.request({
                 url: 'http://localhost:8080/MyMaver/ServletTablaLotes',
                 method: 'POST',
                 params: recordData,
                 success: function() { 
                    var text = response.responseText;
                    respuestaModificacion(text);
                 },
                 failure:  function() { /* ... */ },
                 exception: function () { /* ... */ }
             });
         }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the update records:

```
storeTabla.getUpdatedRecords();
```

Sencha: [update Records](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-getUpdatedRecords)

EDIT:

To send las update to your servlet.

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
                url: 'http://localhost:8080/MyMaver/xxx',
                method: 'POST',

                params: storeTabla.getUpdatedRecords();
                    ...
});
```

EDIT2:

**All Data:** storeTabla.getRange()

**Update fields:** storeTabla.getUpdatedRecords()...

Inspect: **storeTabla.getRange[0].data** you will see the data.

**Example:**

```
var data = [];
var records = storeTabla.getRange();
Ext.Array.each(records,function(element,pos,array){
    data.push(element.data);
});

var dataParams = new Object();
dataParams.data = data;
dataParams.Funcionalidad = 'Modificar';
Ext.Ajax.request({
                    url: 'http://localhost:8080/MyMaver/xxxxxxxxxxxx',
                    method: 'POST',

                    params: dataParams;
                        ...
});
```

Comment: Ok i used that sentence, but how can ido to acces to the save content to do a consult in sql? I would like to save that information like i save the information in a textfield.

Comment: With your function: "modificarRegistro", you are sending a data, you need to do a similar function and send the update records on "params" config value, like a Json (pair value)

Comment: Thanks i have trying to do that, i have incorporated that function ("modificarRegistro") in a listener. I will edit the code to show my last advanced, i think i am near to finish my program. My problem is that i must chaneg this code:  DPEstLot: Ext.getCmp('DPEstLot').getValue(), fot the correct code, but i dont know how.

Comment: DPEstLot: Ext.getCmp('DPEstLot').getValue() --> it's a **Pair value** like {'id' : 1} == {'DPEstLot' : Ext.getCmp('DPEstLot').getValue() }

Comment: Yes it is a pair value because in the servlet i work with the first part of the pair.

Comment: Copy the servlet header code, please, to see the 'in' params.

Comment: I try your last edit, but it dosent work.. is that the full code? i need more code? Thanks.

Comment: depend that you need... But, didnt you had the data on the request ?

Comment: Not, that the problem i dont know how to put all the content of the row that i modified in the grid

Comment: with a 'breakpoint', did you got a 'stop' in the servlet when you did the ajax call ?

Comment: but i need all data not only the change camps... i have trying this but not data is send to servlet:

Comment: i tried that but passing also the next line before the param data.Funcionalidad = 'Modificar'; but it dosent work... i think the problem is in my server that only allow the info in a post mode

Comment: It isn't a object, it's a array, try with the new implement code.

Comment: The same, in this time it dosent wnter in dataParams.Funcionalidad = 'Modificar';

Comment: with this, you wil get on your request, data params object with 2 fields, array called "data" and "Funcionalidad". **request.getParameter("dataParams")**

Comment: then i only must changed my servletTablaLotes to addpat to this?

Comment: Other thing, then when i do request.getParameter("DPAplic"), i obtein the value of the camp DPAplic, or i must do request.getParameter("dataParams") to obtein in a array, and work with that array?

Comment: yes, now you are sending a new object, **dataParams[data,Funcionalidad]**, maybe you need to use a json parser and parse the object to a bean

Comment: i will try to do other thing, to save that function, simply i wont evaluate if i send 'modificar', i evaluated only the other two and then i only need change a little few things.

Comment: when i do a alert(dataParams) i only see [object,object]

Comment: yes, its a object. Use Chrome/Firebug debugger console and put on your code **console.log(dataParams)**

Comment: Thnaks for all i have solved all with  var record = context.record;
                 // get the row's data (will be updated from the last edit)
                 var recordData = record.getData();